# Manually retry an sqs failed job with shoryuken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-sqs, shoryuken

I'm currently building an admin dashboard to monitor our SQS queues, inspired by this [medium post](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/asynchronous-processing-using-sqs-and-shoryuken-2596aec19b4c).

I managed to have everything working fine with this code in my custom shoryuken middelware :

```
class DashboardMiddleware
  def call(worker_instance, queue, sqs_msg, body)
    redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_DASHBOARD_URL'])
    check_if_already_failed(redis, sqs_msg.attributes['SentTimestamp'].to_i)
    redis.incr("sqs-dashboard-enqueued")
    yield
    redis.incr("sqs-dashboard-consumed")
  rescue Exception => e
    data =     {
      id: sqs_msg.attributes['SentTimestamp'].to_i,
      worker: worker_instance.class.to_s,
      queue: queue,
      error: e,
      attributes: sqs_msg.attributes,
      receipt_handle: sqs_msg.receipt_handle,
      body: body,
      enqueued_at: Time.at(sqs_msg.attributes['SentTimestamp'].to_i / 1000)
    }.to_json
    redis.lpush("sqs-dashboard-failures", data)
    raise e
  end

  def check_if_already_failed(redis, job_id)
    jobs = redis.lrange("sqs-dashboard-failures", 0, -1).map { |job| JSON.parse(job) }
    i = 0
    g = nil
    jobs.each do |j|
      g = i if j["id"] == job_id
      i += 1
    end
    unless g.nil?
      redis.lset("sqs-dashboard-failures", g, "DELETED")
      redis.lrem("sqs-dashboard-failures", 1, "DELETED")
    end
  end
end
```

So i display all my failed jobs in my admin dashboard, and details about the error. That was first step. Now i would like to be able to retry manually thoses jobs (one at the time to begin with). I've been searching around the web for a long time now, and didn't find anything to do that (with shoryuken or directly with sqs sdk).

Does anyone have a clue to manually retry a failed message ? 
We already gave a look at dead-letter queues, but we would prefer not to use them.

Thanks a lot for any tips or starting point :)